# How to calculate rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|  acc_id |    dns_id | mail_name    | 
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|        1|         5 | myac1        | 
|        2|         5 | myac2        | 
+---------+-----------+--------------+-
```

I showed to you two records. I have a lot of `acc_id`, but I have the same `dns_id` for a lot of this `acc_id`. How can I calculate how many `acc_id` in the same `dns_id`. I have not only `dns_id = 5`, I have other values. How can I calculate for each `dns_id` number of `acc_id'?

According to my table, I have two `acc_id` in one `dns_id`.

Comment: You should use `count` and `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count(acc_id)` in the select statement and a `group by` with the column `dns_id`. It would look something like this::

```
SELECT dns_id, count(acc_id) FROM [TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY dns_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `GROUP BY` and `count()`:

```
SELECT dns_id, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY dns_id;
```

It groups the results by different `dns_id` and counts the number of rows that were grouped.

Comment: may be SELECT acc_id, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY dns_id;

Comment: @Piduna that is a invalid query and can give your bad results read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/